# SAML IdP SLO (single logout) with Azure AD B2C is failing

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, saml, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have an Azure AD B2C instance with custom policy to allow users to sign with their credential from an external SAML identity provider, the configuration is based on this Microsoft Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy.

The custom policy works except for the single logout (SLO) request. The interesting part is, in Chrome the SLO request works but in Firefox and Safari it fails.

During a sign out flow the browser (Firefox is used in this example) receives a payload with a SAML logout request from the Azure AD B2C. The payload is then loaded into an iframe so that the SAML logout request can be posted to the SAML IdP. In the row 41 in the client side script in the following image you can see a iframe that is being appended to the DOM in the method frameLoader, and this is where the request fails.

[Image of the client side script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM9nd.png)

And here is the stack trace of the exception for the call to frameLoader.

[Image of the stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K8Sd.png)

I thought the issue was related to cookies and cross-site request forgery (CSRF), so I configured a custom domain for the Azure AD B2C, but that didn’t resolve the issue. I also thought it had to do with the SameSite attribute in a cookie, so I tried editing one of them but that didn’t fix the issue.

Is there anyone that has encountered this issue and knows how to resolve it?

***UPDATE***

Further debugging relieved that the issue is related to Firefox way of handling pop-up window. The SAML SLO request works only when I add the URL of the web application as allowed website for window pop-up in Firefox.

Is there a workaround for allowing iframe to be loaded into the parent web application without adding the URL of the web application as allowed website for window pop-up in Firefox?

Comment: Never heard of a dynamic iframe appended to page for signing out. Where does the idea come from?

Comment: This is part of Azure AD B2C sign out flow, which also means that the client side script is part of Azure AD B2C implementation.

Answer (score 1):

it could be a non issue in your use case but there is a feature in Azure LogoutResponses when sent via HTTP-Redirect.  The are encoded in lower case.  the examples you show do indicate a lowercase uppercase difference %3a instead of %3A in the other image.

The work around is to have the SAML library use the REDIRECT_URI in most cases.  As an hack you can replace the letters in the encodings with lowercase characters.

if this is your issue the problem is that the signature cannot match because a and A are not equivalent.

Comment: I was able to run the script locally. I can confirm that exception occurs frameLoader before the call to __.then()__ callback of the __promise__ which actually works. I tested to comment out the part for appending script tag in the formBuilder method, that actually stopped the exception being thrown. So the issue is somehow related to appending the script tag.